# PHP count() counts text array as single element

Tags: php, linux

I am running PHP 7.0.22, under LAMP, on two ubuntu 16.04.

My PHP code is as follows

```
    $str="ls -1 /var/www/dropbox | egrep '*.CEL|*.cel'";
    $result= explode(PHP_EOL, shell_exec($str));
    $fileNames=$result;
    print_r($fileNames);
    echo "<br>";
    $inputFileCount=count($fileNames,1);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "File count:" . print_r($inputFileCount);
    echo "<br>";
```

I get the following on the screen

```
Array ( [0] => prefix1.cel [1] => prefix12.cel [2] => ) 

File count:1
```

It seems to me that the count should be 2.

Comment: Use `glob()` to get an array of files. You're getting empty values. http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php.

Comment: Remove the print_r call for $inputFileCount.

Comment: Considering your array has three items, I'd expect the count to be 3 not 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to get a list of `.cel` files, i.e.:

```
$files = glob("/var/www/dropbox/*.cel");
echo count($files)
```

To loop use:

```
foreach ($files as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
```

Comment: That works!  I modified it to "$files = glob("/var/www/dropbox/*.[cC][eE][lL]");" to make it case insensitive.  Thanks very much,

Comment: Awesome! You're very welcome @OtagoHarbour, glad it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use PHP [SPL Iterator classes](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php).

```
<?php
$folder = '/var/www/dropbox';

// define filtering (match only .cel or .CEL files)
$filter = new \RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator(
    new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder, \FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS), 
    function ($current, $key, $iterator) {
        return strtolower($current->getExtension()) === 'cel';
    }
);

$iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter);

// get count
echo iterator_count($iterator);

// loop over
if (iterator_count($iterator) > 0) {
    foreach ($iterator as $file) {
        echo $file;
    }
}
```

Slightly more code then glob, but also an option.

Answer (score 1):

`ls -l` gives you the long listing showing size, permissions, etc. I don't think this is what you want.

Use `"\n"` as the splitting parameter to split on new lines.

After `explode()` you want to work with the created array.

One more thing: Please use `echo` in your code. `print_r` is for outputting more info about a variable.

```
$str="ls /var/www/dropbox | egrep '*.CEL|*.cel'";
$result= explode("\n", $str);

foreach($result as $filename) {
    echo $filename . "<br />";
}

$inputFileCount = count($result);
echo "<br>";
echo "File count:" . $inputFileCount;
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: Think it's  `-1`.

Comment: Test the code before down voting. `count()` counts elements in an array, if the array is created properly. And, in this case, it is.

Comment: I don't see any down votes.  I was referring to the `ls` switch.

Comment: My apologies! I misread that as a potential down vote!

Comment: `ls` will give you just the file names. `ls - l` gives the long listing. My assumption was that from the OP's original output the only output was the filename.

Comment: `ls - l` likely won't give you much!  I should have been more explicit, OP is calling ls with the switch for single-column formatting.